# Error creating session context via php sdk

Tags: protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

The goal is to create a session context via the PHP V2 SDK like this:

```
$session = $this->contextsClient->sessionName($this->projectId, $this->sessionId);
$contextName = $this->contextsClient->contextName($this->projectId, $this->sessionId, 'test-context-name');

$context = new Context();
$context->setName($contextName);
$context->setLifespanCount(2);
$context->setParameters(["test-param-key" => "test-param-value"]);

return $this->contextsClient->createContext($session, $context);
```

The code works fine without the `$context->setParameters(["test-param-key" => "test-param-value"]);` part. I need to add parameters to the context though.

The error I get is:

```
Exception {#3554
     #message: "Expect message.",
     #file: "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/google/protobuf/php/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php",
     #line: 197,
   }
```

I followed the errors trail and the problem is Google's code in line 197:

```
public static function checkMessage(&$var, $klass)
{
    if (!$var instanceof $klass && !is_null($var)) {
        throw new \Exception("Expect message.");
    }
}
```

is trying to assert if the array passed to the setParameters function is an instance of `\Google\Protobuf\Struct` class in this snippet right here

```
public function setParameters($var)
{
    GPBUtil::checkMessage($var, \Google\Protobuf\Struct::class);
    $this->parameters = $var;

    return $this;
}
```

I would be really glad if someone could help me. I spent a lot of hours trying to figure this out and nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the parameters need to be of type `\Google\Protobuf\Struct`. Also, each of the values need to be of type `\Google\Protobuf\Value`. For your particular example, you could do the following:

```
$paramValue = new \Google\Protobuf\Value();
$paramValue->setStringValue("test-param-value");

$parameters = new \Google\Protobuf\Struct();
$parameters->setFields(["test-param-key" => $paramValue]);

$context->setParameters($parameters);
```

You can look the implementation of these two classes here:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/php/src/Google/Protobuf/Value.php
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/php/src/Google/Protobuf/Struct.php